How to restrict the versions which are not required while deploying .net core web api to a client server
I have a .NET 8 web api solution. if we have 2  versions in it V1 and V2 and client wants only V1 version controller endpoint to be deployed then how to restrict other version V2 from deploying.
I am not able to achieve this.

Just delete the v2 code? You can always get it back from your VCS.

Why does the client get to say at all? This is a server decision. Do you own both sides? I'm not sure why the server has to be restricted. The client just shouldn't call V2. The client and server should be allowed to evolve independently.  You could also split your application up into a V1 and V2. Deployment would then be separate. You can use YARP or some other reverse proxy to handle routing.

Thank You @Robert@Chris for your response. sorry i think my question was not clear. in development we will have multiple versions of controller for different clients. example client 1 wants   id name and  client 2 wants id and full name.  so we will have 2 controller versions V1 and V2 .we need to deploy it in respective client side. so my doubt is how to restrict v2 version for client 1.  It will show supported version both 1 and 2 if I don't restrict 2nd. I hope it makes sense. I am new to this.
